# Combining position:fixed with float

Tags: html, css

I want to design a web page using a fixed header in the top of the page and a fixed menu in the left side of the page. I want that the other parts are floater divs. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: what you had done? show us your html markup, css

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to create a header fixed position and put the menu inside the header and make the menus float left, like this example

Html:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="">test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

css:

```
header {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
}

header .menu {
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}

header .menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px;
}

header .menu a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8TB6e/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class='header'>
<!--Whatever you want to include in the header section-->
</div>
<div class='leftsidebar'>
<!--Whatever you want to include in the left section-->
</div>
<div class='main-content'>
<!--This is your general section-->
</div>
```

Now the CSS will be as,

```
.header{
position: fixed;
top:0px;
height:70px;
background-color: red;
width:100%;
}
.leftsidebar{
position: fixed;/*write relative if you don't want this to be fixed*/
left:0px;
background-color: aqua;
top:70px;
width:100px;
height: auto;

}
.main-content{
position:relative;
left:100px;
top:70px;
}
```

Tell me if this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant float a fixed element as far as I know. 
Think of it this way: All of the three divs will be fixed but looking like they're floating!
Try this CSS:

```
        #header{
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background: black;
        }
        #left_nav{
            position: fixed;
            top: 100px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 10%;
            height: 600px;
            background: red;
        }
        #content{
            width: 90%;
            height: 600px;
            background: blue;
            position: fixed;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        #just_to_activate_the_scroller{
            width: 150px;
            height: 1000px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="left_nav"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="just_to_activate_the_scroller"></div>
        </div>
</body>
```